# Powershell script to fetch name, title, department, manager name, and manager email from text file of groups

Tags: powershell, loops, parsing, scripting, active-directory

I'm trying to write a script that reads from a text file containing the target group names (that have been filtered to have ATLEAST one active user) and fetches the following parameters: name, title, department, manager name, and manager email. Ideally the result only shows users that are enabled and have a manager name and email.

From some intense googling and my limited knowledge in coding and ps, this is what I have so far:

```
[string[]]$arrayFromFile = Get-Content -Path 'C:\sslvpn-active.txt'
foreach($group in $arrayFromFile){
    $searchb = "CN="+"$group"+",OU=SSLVPN,OU=UserGroupsRAS,DC=xi,DC=xxxinc,DC=net"

    foreach($user in $searchb)
        {
            Write-Output $group
            Write-Output "----------------------------"
            Get-ADUser -Filter { Enabled -eq $true } -Properties Title,Department,Manager -SearchScope Subtree | select Name, Title, Department, @{n="ManagerName";e={get-aduser $_.manager | select -ExpandProperty name}}, @{n="ManagerMail";e={get-aduser $_.manager -properties mail | select -ExpandProperty mail}}

        }
 }
```

The text file looks something like this

```
SSLVPN-APC
SSLVPN-XYZ
SSLVPN-Microsoft
SSLVPN-Google
...
```

I would like the result to look something like this

```
SSLVPN-ABC
----------------------
Name        : Joe Smith
Title       : IT Engineer 2
Department  : IT Support
ManagerName : Billy George
ManagerMail : Billy.George@xxx.com

Name        : Matt Damon
Title       : IT Engineer 3
Department  : IT Support
ManagerName : Billy George
ManagerMail : Billy.George@xxx.com

SSLVPN-XYZ
----------------------
Name        : Jen Loo
Title       : Product Designer 3
Department  : Product Design
ManagerName : Ben Smit
ManagerMail : Ben.Smit@xxx.com
...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: i would build a PSCustomObject with the props you want, add that to a $Collection, and then use that to build your report. if you are interested in a _pretty_ report, you may want to import a CSV of the $Collection into excel and do the "oooo! pretty!" there. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are ever getting the group membership. Starting from your sample try the below:

```
    $Properties = @( 'Title', 'Department', 'Manager' )
    
    [string[]]$arrayFromFile = Get-Content -Path 'C:\sslvpn-active.txt'
    foreach($group in $arrayFromFile){
        $searchb = "CN="+"$group"+",OU=SSLVPN,OU=UserGroupsRAS,DC=xi,DC=xxxinc,DC=net"
    
        Get-ADGroupMember $searchb |
        Get-ADUser -Properties $Properties |
        Where-Object{ $_.Enabled } |
        Select-Object Name, Title, Department, 
            @{Name = "ManagerName"; Expression = { (Get-ADUser $_.Manager).Name }}, 
            @{Name = "ManagerMail"; Expression = { (Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties mail).Mail }}
    }
```

Note: The lack of the inner loop.  However, I'm not sure you need the loop at all. Moreover, you may not need to concatenate the distinguished name.

```
    $Properties = @( 'Title', 'Department', 'Manager' )

    Get-Content -Path 'C:\sslvpn-active.txt' |
    Get-ADGroupMember |
    Get-ADUser -Properties $Properties |
    Where-Object{ $_.Enabled } |
    Select-Object Name, Title, Department, 
        @{Name = "ManagerName"; Expression = { (Get-ADUser $_.Manager).Name }}, 
        @{Name = "ManagerMail"; Expression = { (Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties mail).Mail }
```

This somewhat depends on the naming of your groups if they are unique in the environment etc...

You can also park some of the expressions at the top:

```
    $Properties = @( 'Title', 'Department', 'Manager' )
    
    $ManagerName = @{Name = "ManagerName"; Expression = { (Get-ADUser $_.Manager).Name }}
    $ManagerMail = @{Name = "ManagerMail"; Expression = { (Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties mail).Mail }}
    
    Get-Content -Path 'C:\sslvpn-active.txt' |
    Get-ADGroupMember |
    Get-ADUser -Properties $Properties |
    Where-Object{ $_.Enabled } |
    Select-Object Name, Title, Department, $ManagerName, $ManagerMail
```

I wanted to add an example to get the formatting you mentioned:

```
$ADProps = @( 'Title', 'Department', 'Manager' )
$Props =
$ADProps +
@(
    $ManagerName = @{Name = "ManagerName"; Expression = { (Get-ADUser $_.Manager).Name }}
    $ManagerMail = @{Name = "ManagerMail"; Expression = { (Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties mail).Mail }}
)

ForEach($Group in Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\sslvpn-active.txt' )
{
    $Group = Get-ADGroup $Group

    $Group |
    Get-ADGroupMember |
    Get-ADUser -Properties $ADProps |
    Select-Object $Props |
    ForEach-Object{
        $Group.Name
        '----------------------'
        ($_ | Format-List | Out-String).Trim()
        ""
    }
}
```

If I think of a better approach edit further.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is just what I was looking for!

Follow up question:

I added "Export-Csv -Path C:\manager_info.csv -NoTypeInformation" at the end of your first code block and now the results go into a csv which is good but I want to add another column at the front that lists the group.

I tried adding $group in the "Select-object" line but it doesn't seem to like that. Any clues?

Comment: I hate to ask this but can you ask that in another question.  It's hard to visualize what you're describing. Post the code you are currently using, a reference to this answer and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Hi Steven, here is my new question, thanks again

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65670802/add-variable-to-select-object-command-in-powershell